Typescript - Insert element into mutidimensional array if not exists
In one of my angular application I have interface
export interface box {
    row : number;
    col : number;
    value : string;
    selected : boolean; 
};

And in component.ts ,
obj : box[][] = []
allobj : any = []

In further I do get obj as,
this.obj = 
    [
        [{"row":0,"col":0,"value":"00"},{"row":0,"col":1,"value":"01"},{"row":0,"col":2,"value":"02"}],
        [{"row":1,"col":0,"value":"10"},{"row":1,"col":1,"value":"11"},{"row":1,"col":2,"value":"12"}],
        [{"row":2,"col":0,"value":"20"},{"row":2,"col":1,"value":"21"},{"row":2,"col":2,"value":"22"}]
    ]

and will be pushing this object to another array.
this.allobj.push(this.obj)

In next iteration, get obj as
this.obj = 
        [
            [{"row":0,"col":0,"value":"99"},{"row":0,"col":1,"value":"01"},{"row":0,"col":2,"value":"02"}],
            [{"row":1,"col":0,"value":"10"},{"row":1,"col":1,"value":"11"},{"row":1,"col":2,"value":"12"}],
            [{"row":2,"col":0,"value":"20"},{"row":2,"col":1,"value":"21"},{"row":2,"col":2,"value":"22"}]
        ]

And this will be pushed to allobj as one of first value is different (00 & 99).  In short , i want to insert obj array into allobj array if not exists.  means any of the "value" in this.obj is not already present in allobj. I tried below solution but that is also not working.
let temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.obj))
let arr_str = this.allobj.map(JSON.stringify)
!arr_str.includes(JSON.stringify(temp)) && this.allobj.push(temp) 
this.allobj.push(temp) 

need some suggestion.
Playground Demo 2

Please [edit] to provide a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our own IDEs and get to work. That means if you're writing this you should also provide a surrounding context where it makes sense (presumably a class body).  It would also be helpful if you'd give a few short example use cases; like, if original is [{row:0,col:0,value:"99"},{row:0,col:1,value: "88"}] and next is [{row:0,col:0,value:"88"},{row:0,col:1,value:"99"}], do we push or not? Finally, for your code to be a [mre] you need to say more than "that is also not working". In what way specifically is it not working?

• Please include all relevant code as plaintext in the question itself. Links to code are not sufficient to be a [mre]. Until the code is included here as plaintext, the question risks being closed as needing debugging details. • I'm afraid the added examples don't help me understand this. Could you use some words to describe where we should be looking? Or cut down the examples from a 3x3 grid to a 2x1 or something where the differences are obvious?

You can use this function to set the values of both arrays:
let obj : Box[][] = [];
let allobj: Box[][][] = [];

function setValues(val: Box[][]) {
  obj = val;
  const allowedVals = allobj.flat().flat();
  const notFound = val.flat().find(b => 
    allowedVals.find(
      a => a.value === b.value &&
        a.row === b.row &&
        a.col === b.col
    ) === undefined
  );
  if (notFound) {
    allobj.push(val);
  }
}

The function looks for any value in any Box object.
1st call:
setValues([
  [
    {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"00"},
    {"row":0,"col":1,"value":"01"},
    {"row":0,"col":2,"value":"02"}
  ],
  [
    {"row":1,"col":0,"value":"10"},
    {"row":1,"col":1,"value":"11"},
    {"row":1,"col":2,"value":"12"}
  ],
  [
    {"row":2,"col":0,"value":"20"},
    {"row":2,"col":1,"value":"21"},
    {"row":2,"col":2,"value":"22"}
  ]
]);

console.log(obj.flat().length,allobj.length); // 9, 1

2nd call:
setValues([
  [
    {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"99"}, // <-- only difference
    {"row":0,"col":1,"value":"01"},
    {"row":0,"col":2,"value":"02"}
  ],
  [
    {"row":1,"col":0,"value":"10"},
    {"row":1,"col":1,"value":"11"},
    {"row":1,"col":2,"value":"12"}
  ],
  [
    {"row":2,"col":0,"value":"20"},
    {"row":2,"col":1,"value":"21"},
    {"row":2,"col":2,"value":"22"}
  ]
]);

console.log(obj.flat().length, allobj.length); // 9, 2

Playground demo
Playground demo 2

Thanks @Remo for prompt response. But this is not working as mentioned in "Playground demo" link. In second console it prints 9,1 . means not pushing the element.

sorry I made a mistake it should be !allowedVals.includes(valueInObj) not allowedVals.includes(valueInObj)

Thanks @Remo. It worked now. but noticed one issue. I checks only or the value existence , irrespective of it's position . For example if i put "{"row":0,"col":1,"value":"99"}" in one more call. it will skip this because of {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"99"} in second push. ideally it should insert as position is different. please tell how to add row,col also for matching.

I have updated the function to also check col and row properties

Thanks @Remo. but there is one more issue.
2nd push {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"99"}  // only difference // 9, 2 fine ;
3rd push {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"00"} & {"row":1,"col":0,"value":"99"} // 9,3 fine ;
4th push {"row":0,"col":0,"value":"99"} & {"row":1,"col":0,"value":"99"} // 9,3  not fine ;
the 4th push also should happen as it is different box overall.

Please share a playground link so i can understand it better

Edited question and added "Playground Demo 2" . please note , there could be several permutations & combinations as box may differ at any position (row,col)

I'm unsure if the order of the items in the array matters; I don't think I can spend more time on this question. Please take a look at demo 2 in my answer.

Thanks @Remo. i have tested it thoroughly and it worked like a charm.  This is exactly what i want. Thanks a ton for help.
